# Why would GeoDjango and/or PostGIS retain the errors thrown after the error has been fixed?

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I'm playing with GeoDjango and PostGIS and for some reason if I run a migration with some messed up code It throws an error such as

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'foo'
```

Of course it throws an error my code was bad! But then I return the code to what I know is and once was a functioning working state then run:

```
 python manage.py makemigrations bar
```

That runs fine. Then I run..

```
 python manage.py migrate
```

And I get the same error that I got before when I know I removed issue.
There is nothing complicated going on with my code I just started the project and the only things I added where what was required in the GeoDjango tutorial then I added my own models. Is their any Django, PostGIS, or Postgres settings that could be causing the database to retain its errors after a migration? Because the only thing that has worked for me so far is deleting the database and making a new one. This has never happened too me on a regular Postgres/Django project so I feel it may be related to PostGIS or GeoDjango

Comment: How do you "return the code to ... functioning state"? If you do this only to your code, all migrations stay and when you run `makemigrations` new ones are created. Then, every time you run `migrate` it just fails on the same old migrations. So when you "return" your code to its previous state, do the same thing to your migrations, or just delete them and recreate from scratch.

Comment: @Ivan  Deleting the migrations then re-running `makemigrations` resolved the issue. I suppose because `makemigrations` is just a way to set up a staging area for the `migrate` that doing things this way would never cause any issues?